# How to validate Pan card number from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

i have dataframe like below and i want to valid date Pan Number Using python Function

```
     Name     PAN
 0    x     BBDFW7894Q 
 1    s         
 2    A     QWE7892E
```

i want a **function** for this , if PAN is blank/Not valid then return PAN is not present and for valid PAN Number Return True
and i want two df , if True then df_pass else df_fail
df_pass =

```
     Name     PAN
 0    x     BBDFW7894Q
```

df_fail =

```
     Name     PAN
 1    s         
 2    A     QWE7892E
```

i try with

```
def validate_pan_number(value):
  for i in Pan(value.columns):
    if re.match(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$',):
        return True
    else:
        return (value,'is not valid PAN number')
```

but this was not working for the blank value

Comment: This is working for me. The RE does not match for empty strings.

Comment: Edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['valid'] = np.where(df.PAN.str.contains(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$', regex=True), 'Valid PAN' ,'is not valid PAN number')
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
  Name         PAN                    valid
0    x  BBDFW7894Q                Valid PAN
1    s        None  is not valid PAN number
2    A    QWE7892E  is not valid PAN number
```

Later you can `filter` based on valid column:

To Extact valid/invalid pans dataframe via function you can use:

```
def extract_pans(df, valid = True): # default value true
    m = df.PAN.str.contains(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$').fillna(False)
    if valid:
        return df.loc[m]
    return df.loc[~m]
        
invalid_pans_df = extract_pans(df, valid=False)
```

Comment: Is it possible , in one function we Do this Things?

Comment: but this is write but is blank the Pan NUmber then return the message  as PAN is not present